# Improve performance of Entity Framework Core EF with multi include statements

Tags: c#, .net-core, frameworks, entity, ef-core-2.2

I've been trying to improve performance on multiple include statements on my C# .NET Core 2.2 application. Any suggestions on how I could improve this statement?

```
private static void IncludeAssociatedEntities(ref IQueryable<Person> query)
{
    query = query.Include(p => p.Contact);
    query = query.Include(p => p.PersonAddressAssociations);
    query = query.Include(p => p.PersonCorePropertyAssociations);
    query = query.Include(p => p.PersonAssociations).ThenInclude(a =>  a.ParentPerson);
    query = query.Include(p => p.PersonPhones);
    query = query.Include(p => p.PersonOrganizationAssociations);
    query = query.Include(p => p.PersonProjectAssociations);
}
```

Comment: For alternative patterns, see https://gist.github.com/smitpatel/d4cb3619e5b33e8d9ea24d3f2a88333a

Comment: What exactly have you been trying? Save us (and yourself) from suggesting the same things.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the SQL Code Generated and the return you will return a lot of data for this,

It will be much better if you get the desired person then populate it with the desired data.

But if there is a way to improve this it will be amazing...

Also you can use dapper by making an optimized stored procedure then call it